# Parallel execution of the Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: c++, mpi

Actually, the task is to introduce parallelization into the Bellman-Ford algorithm. In our case MPI. The code should count the shortest paths on 4 data sets and take time measurements for each pass. Everything works in a sequential way and in parallel using OpenMP. But I don't understand how to do it on MPI.

I tried to do it, but I don't understand how it should be at all. The code runs successfully and measures the execution time with a different set of data. But the execution time is clearly incorrect. Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <ctime>
 
using namespace std;
 
const int INF = 1e9;
const int Vmax = 10000;
const int Emax = Vmax * (Vmax - 1) / 2;
 
struct edges {
    int u, v, w;
};
 
int j, e = 0;
int peak = 0, start_peak = 1;
edges edge[Emax];
int d[Vmax];
 
int Rank, Numtask, P = peak;
double t1, t2;
 
 
//главная функция
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int weight;
    peak = 400;
 
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Numtask);
 
 
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
 
        //filling the graph with values
        for (int i = 0; i < peak; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < peak; j++)
            {
                weight = rand() % 100;
                if (weight != 0)
                {
                    edge[e].v = i;
                    edge[e].u = j;
                    edge[e].w = weight;
                    e++;
                }
            }
        }
 
        for (int i = 0; i < peak; i++) {
            d[i] = INF;
            d[start_peak] = 0;
        }
 
        if (Rank == 0) {
            t1 = MPI_Wtime();
        }
        MPI_Bcast(&P, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (int i = Rank + 1; i <= P; i += Numtask) {
            for (int i = 0; i < peak - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < e; j++) {
                    if (d[edge[j].v] + edge[j].w < d[edge[j].u]) {
                        d[edge[j].u] = d[edge[j].v] + edge[j].w;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
 
        if (Rank == 0) {
            t2 = MPI_Wtime();
 
            cout <<peak <<" Peaks" << endl; 
            printf("wall clock time = %f\n", (t2 - t1));
             
            //printf("", peak, " вершин");
            //printf("wall clock time = %f\n", (t2 - t1));
            
        }
        peak = peak * 2;        
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the time clearly incorrect? What is the current output you are getting?

Comment: the execution time differs minimally on different data sets. At the same time, with an increase in the number of threads, the time does not decrease, but only increases